# Can the conservation law be extended to the 2d Burgers equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, differential-equations, complex-systems, integrable-systems

I know that for the 1d inviscid [Burgers' equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation) of the form $$\frac {\partial u}{\partial t} + u\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$$ the conservation law converts $u(u)_x$ to $(u^2/2)_x$. However, mainly due to my limited knowledge on how the conservation law is applied and how it works, I do not know how this could be applied to the coupled 2d Burgers equation of the form $$\frac {\partial u}{\partial t} + u\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} + v\frac {\partial u}{\partial y} = 0.$$

I believe that the $u\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}$ would change in the same way it did for the 1d variant, but I have no idea how it could work for $v\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}$. Any help on this matter would be much appreciated.

Alternatively, can I assume that there is a 2d Burgers equation form that is not coupled? In other words, a Burgers equation that is simply an extension of the 1d Burgers equation (inviscid or otherwise) to 2 spatial dimensions, of the form $$\frac {\partial u}{\partial t} + u\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} + u\frac {\partial u}{\partial y} = 0$$
where there is only one velocity component, $u$? If so, how can the conservation law be applied to this equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Considering 2D form with two velocity components**
When considering a 2D Burgers' equation with two velocity components, $u$ and $v$, we have *two* coupled PDEs,
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+v\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}&=\nu\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}\right) \\ 
  \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} &=\nu\left(\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2}\right)
\end{align}
You may be able to write this as a vector equation by defining $\mathbf{u}\triangleq[u,\,v]$ to obtain
$$\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+
\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla \right]\mathbf{u}=\nu\nabla^2\mathbf{u}$$
but I don't know how useful the end result would be for you.

It has been my experience that this form is written as the coupled scalar equations (instead of the vector form) because the scalar form is more directly translated to a numerical scheme (via finite differences) than in the vector form.

**Considering 2D form with one velocity component**
In the case where there is one velocity component in two dimensions (see also [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3089824)),
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\nu\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}\right)$$
it is possible for you to make the substitution the same as in the 1D case:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial y}=\nu\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I am attempting a numerical scheme for solving, the original coupled form is actually much more useful to me. With regards to the one velocity component, again thank you for your answer. It would solve most of my problems if I could use this equation, but I have found no literature that talks about this equation. Whenever, I look up 2d Burgers equation it is always in coupled form. I have also seen the post you tagged, but again, there is lack of proper literature that can prove this equation actually exists.

Comment: Yes, the 1.5D case (2D & 1 velocity component) is unfamiliar to me as well. You may want to see if a comment on the Math.SE post could yield a resource (the arxiv link only shows 1D case).

Comment: Yeah that is the problem. I have a book that also mentions this equation, but I sadly cannot rely on a single book for reference. Thank you for all your help regarding this.

Comment: Ah I just realised I cannot comment on the post as I do not have 50 reputation. Am I allowed to post questions that simply ask for literature sources on this forum? Or is that against community guidelines?

Comment: I'm a couple minutes late, since you have already posted the question, but resource recommendations are on topic here.

Comment: Yes. Thank you regardless. You have been of more help to me than my professors have.

Comment: If $u=v$ then why can't we write it as $f(x+y, 2t)= u(x, y , t)$ for some $f(z,t)$ where $\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial \tau} + f \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 0$ and $z=x+y$, $\tau=2t$.

Comment: Are you asking me, or is this a proof of the fact that a single equation can exist for 2d Burgers ?