# Is there proof that the non-coupled version of the two-dimensional Burgers' equation exists?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, differential-equations

In [this Math Stack Exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3089824/), the OP asks about a solution to a non-coupled variant of the two-dimensional Burgers' equation. I have been looking at all the usual places for literature on this particular equation, but have been unable to find anything so far. The known form of the two-dimensional Burgers' equation is the coupled equations form with two velocity components $u$ and $v$. Could anyone point to literature or sources (that can be referenced) that actually proves that an equation of the form
$$\frac {\partial u}{\partial t} + u\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} + u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac {1}{{\rm Re}}\left(\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}\right)$$
exists?

Comment: What do you mean by, "an equation of the form... exists"?  It is well known that, even in one dimension, solutions of the general initial value problem for Burgers' equation do not exist at arbitrary times.

Comment: @buzz I believe OP uses "exists" to mean it represents a physical scenario & isn't just a mathematical PDE (see [these comments](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/771753/can-the-conservation-law-be-extended-to-the-2d-burgers-equation#comment1732566_771759) on their other question), rather than existence in the common mathematical parlance.

Comment: Yes @Buzz, what "KyleKanos" said is what I mean. Apologies for the confusion in the terminology. What I am looking for is proof that there is a physical basis (or scenario) for the aforementioned equation to exist. That the equation is not just a mathematically correct equation.  Hope this clarifies my intention.